# PHP error when using strtotime

Tags: php, date

Hi I get an error when trying to get date interval using php strtotime function
the code is:

```
 <?php
    $interval = time() - strtotime('1992/08/13');

    //expect to be 18
    // but the output is 1988
    print date('Y', $interval);
 ?>
```

any advice?

thanks

Comment: Your code works fine. Could you provide the actual error?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You're getting the number of seconds from your date to today.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to deal with date intervals in PHP I can't recommend the `DateInterval` class enough. I wrote a blog post on this earlier this week: [Working with Date and Time in PHP](http://webmonkeyuk.wordpress.com/2011/05/04/working-with-date-and-time-in-php/)

There's an example of using it there that should allow you to do what you want to do.

Comment: +1 finally! someone else understood what the question is. DateInterval is the way to go. Check PHP version first though

Comment: Thanks. The inspiration for the blog post came from seeing loads of questions like this!

Comment: `DateInterval` is great; note however that it is available from PHP 5.3 only, and [broken on Windows](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51184).

Answer (score 2):

That is because all time() functions are seconds since `epoch` which is in 1970, so your out is actually 18 years since epoch. If you want it to get the difference in years you will probably have to calculate the difference yourself.

`print $interval / (60*60*24*365.242199);`

Comment: @meouw, Fixed for leap years :)

Comment: hehe, nice, over what time period will this be accurate?

Answer (score 0):

Are you tring to get the years elapsed rather than the actual year?

If so:

```
$year = 31556926;

$interval = time() - strtotime('1992/08/13');
print round($interval / $year);
```

Comment: This is it. The reason why it prints out 1988 is because timestamps start january 1, 1970. 1970 + 18 = 1988

Comment: Pekka is on the money here. You can't treat a time interval like an absolute date.

Comment: I've no idea why this is downvoted. This is the only answer, everyone else is on the wrong track

Answer (score 0):

```
$interval = time() - strtotime('1992/08/13');
```

These PHP functions deal with [UNIX timestamps](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php). That means the number of seconds from `1970. 01. 01`. So `1992/08/13` is transformed into a timestamp (seconds). `time()` gives the current timestamp (seconds). You subtract the former from the latter, and you get the amount of **seconds between those two dates**. This is not a date itself, just an interval.

If you want to get the year, do something like `echo $interval/(60*60*24*365);` which will convert your seconds to years (not accurate, leap years will not be taken into consideration). Though your best option is checking out **@James C**'s link and use his solutions. I just wanted to give some explanation.